# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar JSON con Python?

Tags: mysql, json, python-2.7, diccionarios

como puedo ordenar un diccionario de datos, actualmente obtengo los datos desde una consulta a MySQL.

```js
if __name__ == '__main__':

     cmd = 'SELECT `a`, `c`, `z` FROM equipo WHERE time BETWEEN 1550979126 AND 1550979130'
     data = run_query(cmd)

     equipo = '123456'

     obs = []
     for result in data:
      obs.append({ 'a': result[0], 'c': result[1], 'z': result[2] })

     info = json.dumps({'id': equipo, 'data':obs})

     print(info)
```

El script anterior me retorna el siguiente JSON, pero se encuentra desordenado:

```js
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "a":41.2,
         "c":50.3,
         "z":51.2
      },
      {  
         "a":40.8,
         "c":50.3,
         "z":51.2
      },
      {  
         ...
      }
   ],
   "id":"123456"
}
```

Me podrían dar alguna pista o ayuda para dejar de la siguiente forma el JSON:

```js
    {
      "id": "123456",
      "data": [
        {
          "a": 41.2,
          "c": 50.3,
          "z": 51.2
        },
        {
          "a": 40.8,
          "c": 50.3,
          "z": 51.2
        },
        {
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
```

Desde ya Saludos y muchas gracias por su futura ayuda.

Comment: Has probado un `order by` en tu sentencia SQL?

Comment: En python2, los items de un diccionario no están ordenados. No es problema del módulo `json`. Puedes pedir a `json.dumps` que ordene la salida, puedes usar `OrderedDict`, o bien, puedes pasarte a python 3.7 que no tiene este problema con los diccionarios.